# c# - how to pass values from one page to another without using state management?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two tabs in my home page

In first tab I have treeview

In parent node I have 4 child nodes, each child node has a checkbox

If I checked child nodes then I click the submit button.

I want to show that checked child node values in second tab.

Without using state management I want to do this.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Code :

```
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TreeView1.CheckedNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode node in TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
            {
                string checkedValue = node.Text.ToString();
                activityData = new ActivityData { ActivityName = checkedValue };
                listActivity.Add(activityData);    
                Session["listActivity"] = listActivity;
            }
         }
    }
```

In the above code I am using Session but when I close the browser window values will not be there.So I need alternate solution.

Comment: Without using state management

Comment: @Subin Jacob, query string is also state management technique..

Comment: Where are the multiple pages here? Your title asks about multiple pages, but your questions speaks about window closing. Its not very clear to me

Comment: Database, XML, text file ......

Comment: Passing the values from database

Comment: If I close the window I want to retain the values when open again

Comment: @user2500094 we need more details to help you here, we need the relevant code of the page. And for that matter what do you want to do ? Do you have trouble interacting between the 2 tabs or do you have trouble with saving the state of the selection ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the section "*Getting Public Property Values from the Source Page*" in MSDN Article - [How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> If the source page and target page are both ASP.NET Web pages in the same Web application, and if you transfer execution from the source page to the target page on the server by using the [Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer(v=vs.100).aspx) method, the target page can access public properties in the source page.

Answer (score 0):

it should be called “Persistence”， save your data to database, query it out whenever you use it.